# AngularJS: route.resolve in ES6

Tags: angularjs, routes, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am trying to refactor an existing Angular-Project to use ES6-Modules and `import` statements. This works for the majority of the application, but the `resolve` blocks in my routes are giving me trouble.

As far as I can tell the syntax should be the same as before:

```
$stateProvider.state('stateName'), {
    template: <div></div>
    controller: 'stateCtrl'
    controllerAs: 'ctrl'
    resolve: {
        someData: ['DataService', function(DataService){
            return DataService.getData();
        }]
    }
}
```

However setting a breakpoint in `someData` tells me that my 'DataService' is not resolved properly by angulars dependency injection (or rather: it is resolved properly, but was not initialized yet). The service gets registered on the according module, but its constructor did not get called before entering the `someData`-function.

Since i thought that i got the syntax wrong i experimented a bit and found that some other Services (created with the same syntax and registered on the same module as the `DataService`) are actually initialized and injected properly within the resolve-block.

Do you have any idea where to look or how i can troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ES6, it should be like this:

```
/* @ngInject */
export default function config($stateProvider) {
  resolve: {

    /* @ngInject */
    someData: (DataService) => DataService.getData()
  }
}
```

To read a little more about ngInject see the [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) github page. It does the injections for you.

Comment: Okay, but i still need the array with the string-identifier to make this safe for minification, right? The above is just another syntax for `function(Dataservice) {return Dataservice.getData();}`

Comment: Ah well we use /* @ngInject */ I'll update the answer

Comment: Thank you - I will take a look at ng-annotate! :) Meanwhile i figured out that i forgot to include a nested dependency of `DataService` which was why it could not get instantiated. The Syntax shown above works fine!

Comment: _"it should be like this"_ Can you explain why it should be like that? Syntax aside, it doesn't differ from the OP's code at all.

Comment: zeroflagL; maybe my overzealous love of ES6 has biased me towards that structure - it does appear a lot more readable than the other ES5 style, but that is my humble opinion